# Receive notifications on all answers, comments and new questions for a tag

Tags: support, tags, notifications

I'm interested in receiving notifications for all new questions, all answers and all comments for a given tag. So, if a new question is added with a given tag, receive notification (I think that works already), but I also want to receive notifications whenever an answer or a comment is made on a question with a given tag. How do you achieve this?

Comment: You know that it means thousands of daily notifications for tags like [tag:C#]?

Comment: While this is a good idea for smaller/newer tags; it is pretty annoying with [tag:php] or [tag:c#].

Comment: Clearly, it should be something that can opt to. As you can imagine, in my case this is small/new tag.

Comment: The relatively recent ability to [follow a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/986753) may be a useful alternative, especially if the tag is small.

Answer (score 2):

You can **watch** a tag. Watching a tag will highlight questions with that tag in question lists, though you won't be automatically notified of any new activity in the tag. Here's what you will see when you hover your cursor over a tag:

[image: A screenshot of the tag summary popover that appears on any Stack Exchange site when you hover the cursor over a tag. On the bottom left of the box, there is a blue button that says "Watch tag."]

If you want to get a little fancy, you can grab the RSS link from that popup (the little orange symbol in the top right corner of the tag summary box), and put it into an [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) recipe that can send you a text or [change the colors of your light-bulbs](https://ifttt.com/hue) or [something](https://ifttt.com/channels) for every new [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) question.

I don't know if there is any feature that will send you a notification for every new *answer* or ***comment*** though; that's a little too much information, anyway, IMHO.

Comment: Well answer isn't wrong now, but also does not give real answer, SE simply removed the option to get email notifications for single tag. (There is "Filtered Questions" on se.com but it's way more complex than what we used to have)