# The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network

Tags: discussion, announcements, follow-post

We are happy to announce that the [previously announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345148/upcoming-feature-follow-questions) follow question and answer feature is now live across the Network, including Stack Overflow, all Stack Exchange sites, and all Meta sites. (International Stack Overflow sites will have it turned on in a day or two once we have translations all set.)

You can follow any question or answer (that you did not author) by clicking on the [follow] button that is shown in the menu immediately below the post (alongside the [share] button):

> [image: Get updates on questions and answers]

After you have followed a post, you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices. You will not receive notifications for any action that you performed. As was mentioned in the earlier post, we are not making changes at this point to the notifications received by a post owner, or due to @mentions.

The initial release had been planned to only include question following. Thanks to many folks who chipped in over the past few weeks, we are happy to release both question and answer following at the same time. These are available in both the regular and mobile views.

We are still planning on two more related releases:

1. **Follows profile tab and question listing filter**: A tab for follows will be added to your user profile activity page. Each user will be able to view this tab that will provide a listing of followed questions and answers, with standard sorts, and the ability to unfollow from the listing. Users (with the exception of moderators and authorized staff) will not be able to see this information about other users (nor will it be made public in the API, SEDE, or data dumps).
2. We will be **renaming the Favorites feature to Bookmarks**. As we mentioned in the preview post, the feature will be the same as Favorites, with the name and icon updated to more accurately represent user expectations and usage. And you will be able to both "bookmark" and "follow" a question.

We hope that this new feature will allow you to have better access to the content that you care about and want to keep tabs on.

**Update (June 11, 2020):** The user profile tab and the rename of Favorites to Bookmarks have been released.

Comment: Awesome. Very useful after downvoting or voting to close a question, especially as "unclear". Previously I had no way of knowing when a question was edited to be clear. Now I need to mass-follow questions. :D

Comment: So ... with a million followers you'll become an influencer, right?

Comment: @rene good idea, people following sounds just as useful :p

Comment: Maybe this should get [featured]?

Comment: I’ve already dismissed the “Get updates on questions and answers” tooltip five times. Apparently, I have to do it separately on each site I visit. How can I mark it network-wide as already read?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Sorry, can't easily set it network-wide (the has-seen-popover setting is tied to a site user, not to a network account). Once it is loaded on a site and seen there, it should not show up on that site anymore for you.

Comment: @Jenayah the limit for featured MSE posts is normally 2 (unless it's still 3 from when they [increased it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344254/are-more-than-two-featured-posts-from-this-site-meta-se-supposed-to-appear-on/344255#344255)), it's unlikely this takes priority over the other 2 posts

Comment: All right, never mind. Do you plan to remove the popover completely after some time, when people become familiar with the feature?

Comment: @emil the one time popover will most likely be a permanent fixture for new users. We will probably eventually turn it off for users above a certain rep threshold.

Comment: Now that there are five options/links below the tags it's time to add icons to them to make the difference more obvious and to prevent veterans from constantly clicking the wrong links.

Comment: Got to say, I like it. I somehow missed this and the announcement of it. Either I need to come here more often, or this probably should be featured. Actually, probably both.

Comment: Do we really need this “Get updates on questions and answers” popup? Why not to remove it completely?

Comment: @ks1322 We don't need it. But we want it. It is a useful way to advertise the new feature to users who otherwise would not notice it. We will eventually turn it off for users above a given rep threshold. But it will stay up for a little while in the beginning.

Comment: In International Stack Overflow sites we'll have to wait for the translations (which is fine, I guess), but in International Stack Overflow **meta** sites the links are already enabled and **in English**. Thanks for the "consistency" (and for the - lack of - consideration that international sites have been receiving in the last years, regarding translation issues)

Comment: @hkotsubo sorry about that. It is already live on the Japanese and Russian sites, and Spanish and Portuguese should be up shortly. I have been working with the site mods on getting these translated, but we ended up launching a day earlier than we thought due to scheduling issues this week. So this is on me.

Comment: @YaakovEllis "*We will eventually turn it off for users above a given rep threshold*" That's great news; thanks!

Comment: @YaakovEllis Can the threshold be lower than the association bonus? Then we won't have people getting it on sites they only have an account, while they're very active elsewhere on the network

Comment: @erika that is the plan

Comment: Would you mind to mark this as [featured]? I love the new feature, but I had missed the announcement so I had not upvoted it…

Comment: @Bergi *"the limit for featured MSE posts is normally 2 (unless it's still 3 from when they increased it), it's unlikely this takes priority over the other 2 posts"*

Comment: @Nick Thanks, didn't see those comments. Still, the CC-Licensing post has been featured for a month now, isn't that enough?

Comment: Finaaaaally, great move, I asked for this [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389381/5407848) remember @rene ?

Comment: @YaakovEllis These notifications are not available in `/me/inbox`. How can I retrieve these notifications through the StackExchange API? It is needed to support this functionality: https://stackapps.com/questions/3780/real-time-desktop-notifications-for-stack-exchange-inbox-chrome-firefox

Comment: I'm personally not a fan of the "toast" notification that shows when you unfollow a question. First of all, why does no toast notification show when you follow question? If you follow a question you get a popover, but when you unfollow you get a toast notification. Seems inconsistent - I would prefer a popover for both interactions. And when you click unfollow which is at the bottom left of a post, you have to navigate all the way to the top to close the notification.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Where can I see the list of followed questions or answers ?

Comment: Do I not get notified on tag edits? I didn’t get a notification for [this revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/348173/2) even though I’m following that question.

Comment: @user289905 you should. if you are not, please open up a new case (not tracking new bug reports or feature requests on this post anymore).

Comment: How about some broadcast notice about the update, maybe feature the how do I unfollow a question question? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346423/266284 If a SO dupe of that hadn't just been asked I wouldn't have arrived here & found the (obscure) update.

Comment: Oops there's a follows list but still can't unfollow deleted posts.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Is there a way to unfollow a deleted question? The unfollow button doesn't seem to appear

Comment: related: [proposal for an new badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350495/165773) to be awarded for the first use of this feature

Comment: Yaakov, is this feature rate limited? If yes, would be cool to update [rate limits FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/165773) with details on that (as of now I found nothing about it over there). If no, I would recommend to implement it to prevent potential abuse (one I can think of is some troll can attempt DoS attack by adding follows for millions posts from multiple sock accounts - in the absense of rate limit this probably won't even qualify as punishable offense)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [staff are no longer tracking this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network/345863#comment1173467_345863).

Comment: I do not think that a close is appropriate. If anything, can be locked to prevent new answers.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Closing is the action that has been taken on such posts in the past. Also, which lock reason would you use? The "historical significance" option isn't appropriate, because it prevents those who previously answered this question from interacting with their own answers.

Comment: [related request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352742/165773) to accommodate text of affected comments generated by the system in Low Quality review queue

Comment: Hi, thank you for considering privacy, and not making the list of followed questions private! This is great.

Now could you do the same for Bookmarks, and [make Bookmarks private](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140778)?

Answer (score 102):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): Whether or not the popup is dismissed is saved on the local site account for performance reasons. Saving it on the network account [provides an unacceptable performance hit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1158054_345674). However, the popup is now hidden for users with 15 rep or higher (so it will only be showing for brand new users).

Make the dismissal of the pop-up network-wide.

This popup:

[image]

Shows up when you see a question and haven't dismissed it yet. However, currently, you need to dismiss it separately on every site on the network, and as some users use many sites, this will equate to many useless clicks.

Just like [the banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334137/dismiss-the-meet-the-overflow-and-podcast-episode-banners-network-wide), I'd like it if dismissing it would remove it from all sites, as the feature is the same for each site.

Comment: The user flags that record your having seen the one-time new feature popover are recorded on a per-user basis, and it is not trivial to record them for the network account.

Comment: @YaakovEllis and yet every per-user profile page knows about every single network account of that particular user. Request doesn't seem outlandish to me, and it *is* an utter annoyance. Upvoted.

Comment: @mathieu it is possible to retrieve. But it is an expensive lookup without a non trivial rework. Have to be extra careful with adding any db calls on the show question page (which accounts for most page loads on the network). No extra calls are needed for the current implementation. At sites of this scale, even one extra db call can be very widely felt.

Comment: Just saying, maybe the non-trivial rework might be a good idea at some point. Keep up the good work!

Comment: In the interim, a custom ad^H^Hcrapblock rule will work networkish wide.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Can't store it in local cookies/session? That would solve the issue for a lot of people.

Comment: Or just disable the feature in its totality untill you figure out a way to allow users to disable it globally.. It was annoying the first time it popped up, and I can assure you that it isn't any less annoying after the 10th time either. Or atleast make it less obscure so I can ignore it.. Because right now it scrolls with the page making it a constant eye sore, and it covers up part of the first comment, which makes for bad UX design

Comment: @Remy it should only show up once per site. it is not something that should be an ongoing annoyance.

Comment: @YaakovEllis with HNQ it shows dozens of time to the same user due to the number of sites featured there, even if it's once per site.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Having just dismissed that notification for the umpteenth time since this was rolled out (and having probably a few dozen more waiting on the other sites I have an account on and didn't visit yet), I can assure you it already is an ongoing annoyance. (2 minutes later, dismissed another, this time on EE)

Comment: @YaakovEllis It is of EXTREME annoyance. It is the only reason I came here. It is just horrible.

Comment: We only need to be told of the feature once. This should never ever have been rolled out in its current form, with a per-site balloon. When will SE learn about ***testing*** things?

Comment: @YaakovEllis, I have accounts on ~115 sites and their metas.  I'm *not* looking forward to dismissing that popup more than two hundred times.

Comment: My userscript [Dismiss New Follow Feature Popup On Active Sites](https://stackapps.com/q/8604) will dismiss the "new follow feature" popup on every site on which you have an account. As with many people here, I found it *very* frustrating to need to dismiss this separately on each of the 344 sites where I have an account.

Comment: It's also obstructive - it hides important information, and must be dismissed in order to see that information. A banner or some other way of communicating the information without obstructing the question and comments - two of the main purposes of this site - would be far more friendly and useful. @YaakovEllis

Comment: arrrgh I HATE this popup thing

Comment: @YaakovEllis As someone who browses the RSS feed for HNQ ever day, I've had to dismiss the popup about 50 times so far. I have an account on 123 sites, so I still have about 70 to go. I'm baffled at how you could think this wouldn't be an "ongoing annoyance". Isn't there anybody on staff that uses more than just SO? How long are we going to play this perennial "once per site" game? It's the same thing for April fool's crap we get every year.

Comment: The new feature popover is now hidden network-wide for all users with rep >= 15

Comment: @Yaakov That certainly should prevent further annoyance to nearly everyone. Guess this is as good as status-completed!

Answer (score 83):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): The "follow" button is now located after "share" and "edit".

---

Could you move this button to the right?

> [image]

We are used to the share button on the left, and the "edit" button on the second-left. It's not very user-friendly to change the order of those buttons, and wastes users' time whenever they try to perform the action they were trying to do the first time. =/

Also, as Fabian Röling commented, this view is inconsistent when viewing one's own posts as opposed to others' posts, as the "share" button appears first on the former while "follow" appears first on the latter.

Comment: I like it in that position, even if it is not what I'm used to either.

Comment: Mandatory XKCD: [Every change breaks someone's workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/).

Comment: If it's at the end it does not shake the entire list, just the one.....................

Comment: I guess it won't take long to get used to it, but I've already clicked `follow` several times when I meant to click `share`. Muscle memory is a powerful thing...

Comment: I've also clicked "share" so many times when trying to click on "edit".

Comment: But if you put it at the end, people who are used to flag with the last button will be disoriented ! (+1 xkcd)

Comment: Actually, I just noticed a more important point than "I'm used to it": The leftmost button is now "follow" everywhere **except** your own posts, where it is "share". That should be consistent, so on the right or as an additional button below "bookmark" would be good.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We'll consider the position here. Of course, if we move it after share, then will be the same issue with "muscle memory for the edit button" as well…

Comment: @Yaakov If I understood Suvitruf's suggestion properly, the idea is to move it to the end of the list of actions. That is, after _flag_.

Comment: @fedorqui yes, I understand. That is the suggestion in the answer. The comments also have suggestions to move to after share and after edit as well.

Comment: Another reason to move it to the end of these options, is that following a single post is the least useful feature of the entire site.

Comment: @Pac0 Not true; people who are used to clicking flag will still click flag, because they almost certainly click on it as "option in the 4th position" rather than "let me click whatever is at the end of the list". At the very least this holds true for LTR language sites which is all of them with the exception of maybe Japanese SO.

Comment: @TylerH _"they almost certainly click on it as "option in the 4th position""_ I'd love to see any UI/UX proper source  / research for this claim.

Comment: @Pac0 Plenty has been done; look up the Gutenberg Principle and the Z pattern under the subject of UX. It has been well documented for a long time that our attention and our cursors start out at the left and move to the right on screens, and the reason for that is because our language(s) are LTR languages.

Comment: *Update*: the `follow` link has been moved to be after `share edit` (so it will always be in a consistent position.

Comment: Nice work! Thanks for the swift response, @Yaakov

Comment: Muscle memory means I've now hit this several times instead of Close!

Comment: But "close" doesn't always exist anyway, so I think it's fine.

Answer (score 42):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can we not get follow notifications for comments which reply to us (as that reply already creates it's own notification)?

At the moment if I comment on a question and then follow it, and get a reply I get two notifications for the same comment which seems unnecessary.

Comment: Generally, multiple notifications per post should probably be collapsed into one.

Comment: Thanks @someone_evil. This is something that was supposed to happen but obviously needs to be fixed.

Comment: This is now fixed

Comment: @YaakovEllis Hate to bug you with it, but it appears to be [back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va9Oz.png)

Comment: @Someone_Evil well gosh darnit

Comment: This was fixed again a while back. Can no longer repro.

Answer (score 38):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The search operators should be updated:

- Add operators for following. Maybe `following:y`/`following:n` [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
- Add `inbookmarks:mine` as a synonym for `infavorites:mine` [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Without search, it’s just too tedious to find a post when you’ve followed/bookmarked a non-trivial number of posts.

Comment: @YaakovEllis What’s the reason for the search operators being [tag:status-declined]?

Comment: For the same reason why we can't [add an option to the questions filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350053/51). Requires some big changes behind the scenes to filter by items related only to the user. Bookmarks are public though, different filtering mechanism.

Answer (score 27):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

When one follows a post, change the `following` wording to `unfollow`, to better convey that this is a toggle button, and keep the logic consistent with a verb/verb pair rather than a verb/gerund pair (plus the tooltip reads "unfollow").

Comment: I thought about this as well but I see how *following* has value as well. Not convinced *unfollow* is a better call to action.

Comment: It's like subscribe button on YouTube. When you click on "Subscribe", it changes to "Subscribed" not "Unsubscribe" 

Comment: I realize that the word types are not consistent. But we think that this setup presents the clearest UX to users.

Comment: I would prefer if it was always a verb tense. Follow/Unfollow seems much more natural. You expect to click a verb. I don't expect to click an adjective "following".

Answer (score 26):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Strange behavior when trying to follow deleted answer.

> [image]

1. Follow deleted message.
2. Text changed to **following**. And it's not clickable anymore.
3. After refreshing the page the text becomes **follow** again.

Comment: The `follow` button is no longer available on deleted posts

Comment: @YaakovEllis Why not? You could get notified when it gets un-deleted.

Comment: @FabianRöling: Presumably hiding the option is the band-aid way to fix (don't show UI features that don't work); hopefully in future a proper fix will be implemented.  (Just my guesswork; agreed it would be something you might want to do.)

Answer (score 23):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There is a popup and a tooltip on the `following` button and together they read kind of strange:

- the popup says "follow this answer to receive notifications"... But if it's in `following` state, I'm already following it, am I not?
- a tooltip says clicking the button will unfollow the answer, this is contradictory to the above

> [image: double tooltips]

Suggestion: as both the popup and the tooltip are supposed to read the same thing (at least I think so given what the `follow` popup/tooltip pair reads; see the screenshots [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345677/398063)), just get rid of one of them, keeping whichever increases accessibility the most.

Comment: According to [WAI Authoring Practices](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#button) a `button` element may use `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby` for a more descriptive label, and `aria-describedby` to point to an element that gives a more detailed description of its action. Interestingly, the follow button already has an `aria-describedby` attribute pointing to the tooltip element, so the `title` attribute is redundant.

Comment: This has been fixed. Tooltips should now operate in a more sane way.

Answer (score 16):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Members still receive notifications, even though the post was deleted and it can't be seen 'cause of low reputation.

1. Follow the post.
2. Author deletes the post.
3. Author of the original post leaves the comment (probable I can leave message under the deleted post because I'm a moderator).
4. Member receive notification. But when he click on it to open, he receives 404 error (if he has low reputation).

> [image]

Comment: Only diamonds can comment on deleted content. Author can't.

Comment: @Catija yes, but still the bug with notification)

Comment: This has been fixed. Deleted posts and comments for which you received a follow notification should now result in the notification being deleted as well (which is the standard behavior for other notifications related to deleted posts/comments)

Answer (score 14):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [global-inbox](/questions/tagged/global-inbox) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The links are now working (see below), but IMHO the 'followed question – answer' takes up too much vertical space, and there's a lot of unused whitespace on the right. Perhaps this can be used to make it more compact?

[image]

---

<s>The updates are displayed in the [global inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox) but the links aren't working; they link to the inbox itself, not to the question or answer, as is the case for other notification types.</s>

[image]

Also, the notification type is a generic "message" while the inbox dialog shows something like 'followed question – comment'.

Comment: The 'followed question – comment' template, especially 'followed question – answer', looks odd. Maybe replace it with something along the lines of 'answer to a followed question', 'comment on a followed answer'?

Comment: The links work for me.

Comment: @Alex it's been fixed then (or wasn't deployed at the time, maybe)

Comment: **Update**: The inbox type column on the global inbox no longer wraps

Answer (score 14):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Inconsistent use of English contractions:

> *You are* no longer following this question
>
> *You’re* following this question

Comment: We are now using "You’re" more consistently here. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Have the follow link as a icon button to the left of the post (Question & Answer) Similar to Timeline and the Favorites (soon to be Bookmark)

It would keep the links at the bottom of the post unchanged.

Would need to think about how it may clutter that left side, but it would be a reasonable action grouping in that location

Comment: I agree that would be a more logical location. I don't mind it being in the same line as the share, edit, & flag links, but if it has to be in that line I'd *much* rather it be at the end of the line, not at the start, where I expect the share link.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @nkosi. The link is going to stay on the bottom for the time being. We have a project in the planning stages to give a refresh to the layout of the post (including side and bottom menus), and ideas similar to yours are under discussion there.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Please standardise the use of pop-ups. This is a view of the "default" pop-up:

[image]

This is a view of the `follow` pop-up:

[image]

Comment: Yes, they are inconsistent. We have a lot of tech debt in this area, and are not going to be addressing it as part of the current project (it is more than just this one tooltip). We are planning a general UI refresh of the post header/menu, and will be taking care of all of this stuff at that time.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The `follow` tooltip is displayed under very specific conditions, which are not "user natural".

---

Steps to reproduce (Windows 10, Firefox 74.0):

1. Pick a post you have never, ever followed
2. Hover over the `follow` button; this is what you should see (popup but no tooltip):

   > [image: popup but no tooltip]
3. Follow the post by clicking the `follow` button; the text changes into `following`
4. Unfollow the post by clicking `following`
5. Repeat step 2, namely hover over the `follow` button; notice that now there's a tooltip:

   > [image: same as above with a tooltip added]

This is already buggy behaviour, but you can take it further:

6. Reload the page (you're still not following the post)
7. Repeat step 2, namely hover over the `follow` button; the tooltip disappeared again:

   > [image: same as first screenshot: no tooltip]

Comment: **Update**: tooltips have been fixed and now work in a more sane manner

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On Google Chrome for Android, when not using the responsive design, the arrow does not point to follow. In the screenshot below it instead points to close:

[image]

Update 2020-04-01: the bug is still present, e.g on [Is Traveling to France in September Safe Concerning the COVID-19 Pandemic?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/156445/1810):

[image]

Update 2020-04-05: the bug is still present, e.g on [Is Traveling to France in September Safe Concerning the COVID-19 Pandemic?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/156445/1810)

[image]

Comment: **Update**: The popover should now point to the follow link properly on both mobile and regular views.

Comment: @YaakovEllis thanks, the bug is still present, e.g see updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, I see. I fixed it before moving the `following` link to the right, so now have to undo my first "fix"

Comment: Arrow should now be pointing to the link in both regular and mobile views.

Comment: @YaakovEllis thanks, the bug is still present, e.g see updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please add the ability to follow deleted posts; from [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network/345675?noredirect=1#comment1158525_345678) it appears it was planned (the button appeared) but dropped:

> The `follow` button is no longer available on deleted posts – Yaakov Ellis♦

There's a couple reasons why one may want to follow deleted posts: checking if the author revamped the post, to possibly cast an undelete vote on it, etc.

---

Related [support](/questions/tagged/support) question: if I follow a post that is later deleted, is it:

1. removed from my follow list, and
2. do I get a notification about it? I'm not sure if deletions are covered by the "notices":

   > you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices.

Comment: Can you please add this as a feature request in a separate post. No longer tracking things here.

Comment: @YaakovEllis sure, done https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350505/398063

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

I was following [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345859/622284), waiting for an update from Yaakov on a pending bug report's fix.

When the post was edited, I correctly received a notification. However, the wording of such notification seems to be specific to Stack Overflow posts, as it says "followed answer - code edited." Given there was no code to edit, that seems to be a bit off.

[image]

Here's a [link to where it points me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/345859/revisions), if that's relevant at all.

Could this be changed to "body edited" or "post edited," so that the wording can apply across all networks?

Comment: There is code in place that attempts to identify whether or not code is being modified in the edit. So it is not a SO-specific function. It will only include "code edited" if this is detected. Otherwise will be "followed answer — edited".

Comment: @YaakovEllis Ahh, I see now. That makes sense. Cheers for the update :)

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

It looks like following a question only alerts you to activity on the question proper, but not activity on answers to the question. Thus if you truly want to completely follow a thread you would have to individually follow each answer in addition to following the question.

Can you make it that following the question automatically follows all answers that are (or will be) posted to that question? Or if there are people that might not want to follow every answer, can you make it a selectable  option to follow all answers along with the question?

Comment: _"Or if there are people that might not want to follow every answer"_ Definitely me! And I would imagine that a lot of users don't want that to be the default. If I follow a question, I don't want to be notified of every comment/edit on every answer that question receives. Imagine on Meta where questions usually receive tons of answers and comments.

Comment: I would say that even making it a selectable option isn't worth it. Right now, if you follow a question, you'll get notified of every answer. If you're really that interested, you'll go ahead and read every answer you get notified of. Then, you can follow those answers (or some of them) while you're at it.

Comment: Huge no. It will flood the inbox. Additional "super follow" option will be fine.

Comment: We are definitely not going to make a question subscribe auto-subscribe to all answers, for reasons that other comments have outlined. And as far as making it optional to auto-follow answers: while that is not going to be happening in the near future, it is something that we will keep in mind for potential additions in the future.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When a followed, deleted question is navigated to, `updateFollowUI` throws an error, resulting in most site Javascript failing to execute.

To reproduce:

- Have 10k+ reputation, so you can see deleted posts
- Follow a question that's [very close to being deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today)
- Wait until it's deleted (cast the 3rd vote yourself if you want)
- Reload the question page

You may notice that the page was generated *without* the Follow/Following link at the bottom. If you open the console, you will see an error.

[image]

If you try to interact with any of the Javascript on the page, it will not function. For example, clicking to expand a long comment chain will result in the `<a class="js-show-link comments-link" href="#">` moving the viewport to the top of the page, and nothing else. Clicking on Reopen/Undelete/Flag has the same behavior. The topbar dropdowns (messages/reputation) don't appear either, they just become normal links.

The problem is due to the fact that the deleted question was generated without a Follow/Following link, and the `updateFollowUI` function has:

```
var updateFollowUI = function ($followBtn, isQuestion, isFollowing) {
    if (!$followBtn) {
        return;
    }
    // ...
    var currentGpsTrack = $followBtn.data('gps-track');
    var newGpsTrack = currentGpsTrack.replace(/item:[ ]?[\d]+/, "item: " + newTrackItemType);
```

The `$followBtn` parameter is expected to be something like `$('.js-follow-post')`, the Follow/Following button wrapped in jQuery. The `if (!$followBtn) return` checks to see if the parameter is truthy - but it's a jQuery collection, so it is truthy, even if no `.js-follow-post` elements matched the selector. If the collection has no elements, `$followBtn.data('gps-track')` returns `undefined`, so `currentGpsTrack.replace` throws.

The fix might be to replace

```
if (!$followBtn) {
    return;
}
```

with

```
if (!$followBtn.length) {
    return;
}
```

On my end, at least, if I do that, everything starts working again.

Could also be fixed by excluding Follow stats (`VoteTypeId:21`) from the `votesCast` passed to `StackExchange.question.init` when the question is deleted.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396304/6045800). When I navigate to a page with an answer I was following that was deleted, most of the functionalities are disabled and I get an error in the browsers console

Comment: fixed, thanks for reporting this.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

When following fails and the server responds with an error, a non-existent variable is referenced, resulting in a JS error. As a result, the error message from the server is not displayed.

Easiest way to reproduce is to press the "Follow" button on a deleted answer. The server responds with `"This post has been deleted; deleted posts can't be voted on"`, but this message doesn't get displayed in the UI.

In the `follow` function, there is:

```js
submit({
    $target: $followBtn,
    postId: postId,
    voteTypeId: voteTypeIds.follow,
    undo: originalIsFollowing, // if it is currently following, that means that we now have to undo the vote
    success: function(clicked, pid, data) {
        if (!data.Success) {
            updateUI(originalIsFollowing); // <---------------------
            showErrorMessage($followBtn, data.Message);
        } else {
```

The problem is that there is no such variable named `updateUI` in scope, so the error visible in the console is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: updateUI is not defined

(this is also one of the very few variables which didn't get minified - which makes sense, because there's no known identifier to minify)

This was probably meant to be a reference to `updateFollowUI`, which *is* a function in scope there, whose parameters are `($followBtn, isQuestion, isFollowing)`, so the line should probably be

```
if (!data.Success) {
    updateFollowUI($followBtn, isQuestion, originalIsFollowing);
```

Using the above code results in the error message from the server being displayed properly, and the follow button text reverts to `Follow` per `updateFollowUI`, as desired.

Could also remove the `follow` button entirely from deleted answers, as is currently done with questions.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Can we have a one-time option to follow all our bookmarks nées favourites, network-wide? It can be a time-limited offer, buried somewhere in the options, and a butt-ugly button.

I am asking because I would want to follow most of the questions I have favourited, but don’t want to go through all of them to manually follow them.
I can still unfollow the exceptions when I ever get a notification due to this.

Comment: It's worse for me: I originally expected "favourite" to be like "follow", then when I realised that wasn't true, I migrated all my favourites to a list of links in Google Tasks "check later" and now I need to migrate it all back. But I guess having some UI thing in which I can mass-paste links to follow is too much to ask for, barely anybody except me would use that.

Comment: I feel your pain. But we just don't have the time to spend on this. However, we will consider adding a follow button on the favorites tab in your profile (no promises)

Answer (score 5):

As one of the people who missed the announcement of this feature, I was baffled by the tooltip with the ringing bell graphic. I did not see the little triangle which points to the "follow" link. I interpreted it as a button. I clicked on it, and nothing appeared to happen.

Consider finding a way to visually emphasise the tooltip's relationship to the "follow" link more. Maybe make the triangle stand out better. Maybe even change the wording to mention the "follow" link.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Feature request: please add some sort of preference so that when I follow a question I only get notified to answers and **don't** get notifications about comments.

Comment: You could use `[tag:feature-request]`.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q Huh, did not know I could do that.  Thanks!

Comment: If this is implemented, please make it optional. On some questions, I'd like to follow the comments. (What about edits? Comments to answers?)

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Add a `Following` tab in the user profile, perhaps next to `Bookmarks` that shows the list of questions you are following:

[image]

Comment: This is part of the original scope of functionality, being worked on right now.

Comment: @YaakovEllis: Indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When a question that is being followed is deleted, there's no apparent way to stop following it. For example, for me in the Math SE, there's the second entry below:

[image: List of followed items showing a deleted post]

When I click on that entry to see the post, there's no indication anywhere on how I may possibly unfollow it:

[image: Deleted post being followed]

If I instead click the "View More" link at the bottom of the "Followed Posts" section, I get a list of the followed posts, as shown below:

[image: List of followed posts]

Unfortunately, clicking the red "Unfollow" link here gives the following error message:

[image: Error message when try to unfollow a deleted post]

This seems like a somewhat inappropriate error message as I'm not trying to "vote" on it.

I don't see anything else to try. Is there any current way to allow us to stop following a deleted post and, if not, are there any plans to add one (e.g., perhaps allow the "Unfollow" link to work for a deleted post)?

**Update:** A closely related question [How do I unfollow a deleted question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346423/562482) has been updated to ask about this same issue.

**Update #2:** As stated in [Cannot unfollow locked post from Following tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349629/562482), this has now been fixed, as I've confirmed by clicking on "Unfollow" to get the following

[image: Deleted post now unfollowed]

with the entry disappearing when I refresh the list.

Comment: Hmm, this is a good point. While it's technically a "vote" behind the scenes, it should probably be treated as a special case here.

Comment: @AdamLear If it's a vote, then why doesn't it show up as such in the `VoteTypes` table in SEDE?

Comment: @Ollie Post follows are private, so we don't export them to SEDE and there's no need to export the vote type id either.

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Add the ability to unfollow one's own question or answer.

Comment: Hmm. I thought that too at first, but I'm not really sure how I feel about it.

Comment: Post dissociation accomplishes this somewhat.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog but it is not reversible and mods have to manually approve it, right?

Comment: I highlighted this on the [original preview post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345148/51) as something that we were thinking about, but are not doing yet, and we were looking for feedback on this. Adding the ability for a post owner to no longer receive notifications has the potential to break some implicit social contracts that have long been in existence on the site (relating to the OP's role as post caretaker) and doing so can have some potentially big repercussions. We invited discussion there and no one responded.

Comment: I agree with @Yaakov here. I believe this will cause more harm than good, overall.

Comment: @YaakovEllis thanks I hadn't seen this post. I added the feature request there: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345718/178179

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou Yaakov didn't take a stance in their comments, they just raised some potential issues.

Comment: @Franck I know, I agree with the part he said it will break something, hence more harm than good and the reason I am against it.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [flag-dashboard](/questions/tagged/flag-dashboard)

The 'follow' link is also visible when expanding a post in the moderator flag dashboard, but when I click it, I get the message you usually get when *unfollowing* a post, and I end up not following the post.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Pluralisation issue in the "Following" tab:

> [image: screenshot of a followed question with a single answer]

This should read `1 answer`, without the extra `s`, to be correct and consistent with what's written when you read the question:

> [image: question page showing no extra "s"]

Comment: Do we still get [blundgeoned for pluralisation bugs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/398063)

Comment: Also happens with "1 followed posts" if you're following only 1 post.

Comment: No, because Jeff Atwood has left SE and therefore can no longer bludgeon us.

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Make signage of "accepted answer", "non-accepted answer", "question with no accepted answer" and "question with an accepted answer" consistent between tabs.

For instance, this is how it's shown in the new "Following" tab:

> [image: three followed posts, a regular answer (grey A), an accepted answer (green A + checkmark icon), a question with an accepted answer (grey Q + checkmakr icon)]

This is how these same posts are seen from the "Newest posts" tab in the front user profile:

> [image: same posts as above, but no checkmark icon, the Q is green]

Sometimes the checkmark appears as an icon, sometimes it doesn't, in which case the Q or A logo is coloured in green, when it was still grey (for the Qs) in the Following tab... This is inconsistent (confusing?) signage.

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [profile-page](/questions/tagged/profile-page) [wording](/questions/tagged/wording) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When I'm following only questions, and filter on 'Answers only' in the [following tab on my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=following), it says

> You are not [following any posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network).

Strictly speaking this isn't true; better would be to change that to "You are not following any answers."

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [network-profile](/questions/tagged/network-profile) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Just like we have [a list of all <s>favorites</s> bookmarks across the network](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bookmarks) in our network profile, can we have one for followed posts as well? Or would such a feature have severe performance problems? (I don't know how the account list and the bookmarks list work, whether you're querying those from a single database or (less likely) 170+ calls to each database.)

Comment: Realistically speaking, I don't think we'll have the bandwidth for this unless it's turns out to be an overwhelmingly requested thing, but I'll bring it up internally. Off-hand, the implementation here would likely look like another DB table, aggregator bits to sync follows into it, plus the se.com views for display.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Questions I was following that were then deleted still show up in my list of *Following* stuff. But if I click to unfollow any of them, I get a message saying "This post has been deleted; deleted posts can't be voted on". Can I unfollow a deleted question please? Otherwise my following list can only accumulate lots of deleted questions.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Follow notifications from comments don't go away when the comment is deleted, unlike normal notifications.

This is probably related to [this other bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345683/681403), but occurs for non-deleted posts.

Comment: Follow notifications for comments are now deleted when the comments are deleted.

Answer (score 3):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
>
> Yes, GDPR data requests will include a list of posts that the requestor has followed

Has the new data that is obtained from users here been added to the response body from a GDPR data request including posts being followed etc.?

If not is there an ETA on when it will be?

Comment: I am in the process of verifying this

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The popup appears squashed when viewed in portrait mode on iOS Chrome:

[image]

Comment: This is one Yaakov is at least aware of, repro on Android FF

Answer (score 3):

> [image]

I followed a question for testing purposes two hours ago.

According to [another answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345695/392799):

> Follow notifications from comments don't go away when the comment is deleted, unlike normal notifications.

Is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

But as shown above it is **not yet fixed.**

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Two notifications are shown for one comment, meaning one was deleted. Further, the inbox does not reflect the *revised* comment, rather the two original comments before the delete and edit.

---

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

When more than one change takes place, group them as happens with comments on own posts (show *only* latest). And the user can check was else was changed. As it is right now, *one follow* drowns the inbox.

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When unfollowed also as shown (after a refresh), the inbox items remain.

Answer (score 3):

[discusion](/questions/tagged/discusion)

Tooltip background color for `follow` button is white with black text whereas background colors for all other buttons are black with white text. This creates **inconsistency in tooltip colors** among the options underneath a post.

[image]

Firefox ESR 68.9.0 on Debian 10 GNU/Linux.

Comment: No repro Firefox 77.0.1 (64-bit) Windows 10 2004. (All tooltips besides follow show native browser tooltips (https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0uD9.png))

Comment: Linked: [Please make all of the link tooltips the same style as the “follow” tooltip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396891/please-make-all-of-the-link-tooltips-the-same-style-as-the-follow-tooltip).

Comment: Repro'd Google Chrome 80.0.3987.132 (64-bit), Ubuntu 19.10. The tooltip for "follow" also shows up much more quickly than the other buttons, and looks more inline with Stacks.

Comment: Repro'd Google Chrome 83.0.4103.106 (64-bit), Windows 10 1909. I second Mithical's statement about the "follow" tooltip also appearing much quicker.

Comment: This is probably a darkmode bug (or rather lack of feature) rather than a follow bug, likely your system tooltip colours are being shown for share/edit/close etc. and so are dark, however dark mode is only supported on SO main right now, I assume that if you hovered a follow button on SO main it would appear dark. And indeed this [has been reported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits/396760#396760) and deferred

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Edits to followed questions that have been deleted should not trigger an inbox notification if a user does  not have the reputation to view deleted questions.

Comment: Please add feature requests as new MSE post. We are no longer going through and following up on feature requests left as answers to this post.

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Access as a moderator, more menu items are displayed, so if the post is edited, the display will be corrupted.

**Edited post:**
[image]

**Unedited post:**
[image]

Comment: We are planning a UI refresh in this area that will take care of the current issues that you are highlighting. Unfortunately, there is not much that we can do about this until that project is able to move forward. So marking this as declined (though it will eventually be addressed)

Answer (score 2):

> [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
>
> YE: We had been planning a feature to add a "Followed" filter to the questions listing page. This is no longer part of the active plans. There are some complications with implementation which make that would require architectural changes to other parts of the system in order to implement this. So any possible implementation would have to wait for those to happen (it is on a list of things to do, but no time frame at this time).

The announcement states that:

> Additionally a filter in the [more] drop down on the Questions listing page will be added for `Followed`.

I'm not seeing this filter in the drop down:

> [image]

Note: The reason I've mentioned it is that there is a feature request for a `/help/follow` page that Catija and I are working on. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350054/267099.

Comment: Yes... Clearly under the heading: *"We are still planning on..."'*... And the update doesn't include that, so it's still not added, this isn't a bug

Comment: @nick Yeah, but the rest of this "We are still planning" paragraph has already been done.  The reason I've called it out is that there is a feature request for a `/help/follow` page that Catija and I are working on. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350054/267099.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The `follow` link appears under answers in the Late Answers and First Posts review queues, but it does not work. The tooltip appears when hovering over `follow` but no action occurs if you click the link. Opening up the question and clicking the link on the same answer works as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Whilst it's not the end of the world, the 'followed' and 'unfollowed' messages on clicking follow/unfollow are glaringly inconsistent.

Clicking follow produces a box with pointer to the `follow` button.
[image]

However clicking either the same link (now labelled `following`) or the `unfollow` link at the bottom of the popup message produces a blue banner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

#### New Users who post a Closed-as-Duplicate Question

This feature will be a huge improvement for Following dupe-target questions when your own question has been closed as a duplicate.

No longer will *only the question asker* receive the years-long benefit of notifications for new answers and updates to a Question.

**Suggestion:** strongly guide people who have had their Questions closed as a duplicate to follow the dupe-target Question. Do this via a "Follow" button in the Duplicate Post Notice or some other workflow that makes it easy and apparent.

This could be done for all users, but would be especially beneficial for new users. Perhaps even flag new users to follow the duplicate target automatically? Following the dupe target would be a welcoming "good" result of having your question closed and would *"drive engagement"* from those new users.

Comment: Auto-following dupe posters is not a good idea, because very many duplicates are duplicates of pretty active questions, so many people would suddenly get not so relevant notifications. And especially new users would be surprised why they suddenly get notifications for some post and don't always know how to un-follow.

Comment: We are planning on some ideas similar to this in the [Close UX project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394871/51) where new types of notifications will most likely be used to inform users about their posts that have been closed. But we are not going to be implementing this suggestion here, and I do not think that we are going to ever auto-follow a user to a post that they did not choose to follow.

Comment: Auto-following was not the main point of this answer, FWIW.

Answer (score -1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Since the "Following" tab is hidden for other users, move it at the end of the tabs row to stash it with the other tabs only you can see (Responses, Votes).

My profile:

> [image: row of possible tabs]

Someone else's profile, where did the "Following" tab go?

> [image: almost the same options as above, but with a shift]

Comment: I'm not sure about this. It's related to bookmarks, so keeping it next to that tab seems logical too.

Comment: @Glorfindel true, I can see arguments for both sides

Comment: I'd rather optimize for the case when the tab is there. As Glorfindel said, keeping it next to bookmarks is a logical position for users who can see it.

Answer (score -2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Show followers count of a post, same way we can see how many users have bookmarked a question.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't going to happen. We are concerned that if posts have the number of followers marked, that they will become magnets for answer/comment spam.

Comment: @Ömer for stats only, we can ask to have it added to SEDE. Yaakov, is this feasible?

Comment: We don't have any plans to add it to SEDE at this time, for the same reason.

Answer (score -3):

> [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
>
> **Update**: We have added logic to the API to properly identify Followed-Post-Activity inbox rows correctly. This is the most that we can do to help fix this. In our testing, the apps no longer crash (but we are unable to perform comprehensive testing on different devices, nor can we make any changes to the actual apps to address issues that still exist with these).

The notifications only appear on the site; the app (at least iOS) does not show these notifications:

[image: screenshot of notifications on website]

[image: Screenshot of notification on app]

Comment: The apps have been [declared obsolete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028), this is likely a non-issue

Comment: There's no way to have these appear in the apps without updating the apps, because the notification types are hard-coded into the app. We no longer do any development on the apps. Just be glad that the new notifications don't *crash* the app like they seem to do on Android.

Comment: That's still very good to know for people who are still using those applications (because the mobile browser and responsive design versions are still missing some features).

Comment: "Just be glad the new notifications don't crash the app" .... oh dear... I mostly use the app for notifications ._.

Comment: Looks like we might be able to fix this server side. Looking into it.