# How to disable "follow post"

Tags: support, follow-post

There's now this super annoying pop up on all questions across all sites:

[image: Get updates on questions and answers]

To turn it off

you

have

to

hide

it

every

single

time.

How can it be disabled permanently on all questions across all sites?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network) - notably [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345674/398063) which is [status-declined].

Comment: Hm. It only turnt up once for me

Comment: I've seen it on 2-3 sites already despite dismissing it on the first and (I *think*) the second one I saw it on.

Comment: I've created a userscript which will dismiss this on every site on which you have an account: [Dismiss New Follow Feature Popup On Active Sites](https://stackapps.com/q/8604)