# Dismissing the little popup box advertising the new "follow" should be network-wide

Tags: feature-request

Dismissing the little popup box advertising the new "follow" should be network-wide, rather than bothering me on Each And Every Site. :-) (And the same for other future new features...)

Comment: This was [declined here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345674/622284).

Comment: Thanks @Spevacus. That's unfortunate but sadly unsurprising.

Comment: The reasoning is fair, I suppose. It's apparently a very taxing database call to reference a network account from the scope of a specific site. Buuut, once you've dismissed the notification on the sites you follow, you should never have to worry about it again.

Comment: @Spevacus - But that expense would only have to be incurred once, when I dismiss the notification. But it wasn't your decision, so it's probably a bit silly of me to post counter-arguments to you... :-)

Comment: How dare you argue against me! But nah, imagine the expense you described... but multiplied across all users across the network today. The servers would be sizzling. Yes, it'd be largely over after the initial onslaught, but I suppose they've already thought of that.

Comment: @Spevacus - :-) Sounds like they need to step back and do a bit of redesign around common network stuff, some kind of hub for network-wide user settings.