# What's this new “get updates” box and why doesn't it have any functions?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

I've seen this across nine different Stacks I follow, so I presume it's everywhere.

The last few days, I've been getting a little box in most (all?) questions with a bell icon inside and "get updates on questions and answers" -- but there's no active text in the box, the bell isn't active, and the only function that appears to be available is to close the box with the X in the upper right.

Is this a preview of an upcoming feature, a bug, or a bugged/failing feature that's supposed to be live? I've looked in other parts of the UI and don't see anything that lets me specifically follow a given question or answer. What's up with the bell box?

(referred here from boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network)

Comment: Aha!  Nobody out in the boonies (the low-traffic and newer stacks) seems to know thsi is there, and it's subtle enough to miss even if you're looking for what the "bell" box is about...

Comment: Okay, I got a notification that this question was reopened, but now it shows closed by a mod, half an hour after it was closed as a dup when I acknowledged the linked question.  I'm confused?!

Comment: Sorry for the chaos, I reopened then closed again since it didn't show the dupe target due to a bug.

Comment: @Mark it's not fixed yet, the bug is only when OP self closes.