# "Follow" text should change to "Unfollow" when a question is followed

Tags: discussion, follow-post

The behavior of the "follow" button is inconsistent with the other similar buttons under a question.

The labels on the other actions change to the opposite of their original label once an action is taken:

- `close` -> `reopen`
- `delete` -> `undelete`
- `follow` -> `following`?

Shouldn't it be `unfollow`? In other cases, its' showing a label to reverse your action, not showing the current state of the action. It seems inconsistent.

Comment: This was [proposed and rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345676/390409) already.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Whoops. I didn't think to check the answers of the announcement. My bad.