# Add the ability to follow deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-posts, follow-post

I'm reposting my [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) from [the Follow feature announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345863/398063) as I was asked to by @YaakovEllis in [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network/345863?noredirect=1#comment1173467_345863):

> Can you please add this as a feature request in a separate post. No longer tracking things here.

---

Please add the ability to follow deleted posts; from [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network/345675?noredirect=1#comment1158525_345678) it appears it was planned (the button appeared) but dropped:

> The `follow` button is no longer available on deleted posts – Yaakov Ellis♦

There's a couple reasons why one may want to follow deleted posts which they weren't following before (so not related to [this current bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346423/398063)): checking if the author revamped the post, to possibly cast an undelete vote on it, etc.

---

Related [support](/questions/tagged/support) question: if I follow a post that is later deleted, do I get a notification about it? I'm not sure if deletions are covered by the "notices":

> you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices.

Comment: I’d also like to be able to follow locked posts in case they get unlocked later.

Comment: The corollary to this would be the ability to unfollow posts that have been deleted (or locked). Something that's been reported as [a related problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346423/389569). Perhaps allowing one would automatically allow the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Following deleted posts is now feasible:

[image]