# Is there a keyboard shortcut to follow questions/answers?

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts, follow-post

Apologies if this has been asked before, I looked but couldn't find any mention of it.

We can now [follow questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/276202), which is great. Is there a keyboard shortcut to activate the feature, similarly to how there are already keyboard shortcuts to move between questions (`j`, `k`), get the *share* link (`l`), edit the post (`e`), comment (`c`), open the "go-to" panel (`g`), etc.?

If there is one, it should probably be added to the list of shortcuts given when typing `?`.

If not, are there plans to add one?

Comment: I [don't see it](https://dev.stackoverflow.com/content//Js/keyboard-shortcuts.en.js), I don't think there is one (yet)