# Is there a keyboard shortcut to open the flag menu?

Tags: support, keyboard-shortcuts

I have the "Enable Keyboard Shortcuts" option enabled in my preferences, but I can't find one to open the flag menu.  As there are shortcuts to open the "share" link (`l`), and to edit the post (`e`), and to comment/answer (`c` and `a`, respectively), where can I find one that opens the flag menu, which I use frequently?

Comment: The canonical is *[Keyboard shortcuts are now integrated into the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166)* (2014). [Screenshot of keyboard shortcuts](https://stackapps.com/questions/2567/official-keyboard-shortcuts) (somewhat out of date). Press `?` to get the list displayed. Though that post is somewhat low on details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, there's a flag keyboard shortcut available.

Press the <kbd>?</kbd> key to open the list of available keyboard shortcuts. Then, press <kbd>M</kbd> to open the "Moderate..." menu.

[image: The moderate keyboard shortcut menu]

From this menu, the "flag" option is available with the <kbd>F</kbd> key, granting you access to the various flagging options.

[image: The various flag options, screenshotted]

Comment: Spevacus, is there one to follow a post?  Seems like the only missing one...unless I'm wrong again ;)

Comment: @Ollie Nope! But there's an [open feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346802/622284) on such a shortcut.