# Cannot unfollow locked post from Following tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, spam, locked-questions, follow-post

Initially I was unable to unfollow deleted posts from the Following tab in my profile.

That seemed to been fixed recently so I was cleaning out the deleted posts when I encountered one that would not unfollow.

[Conversion pdf document which includes tables to csv file using python or any other langaue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135343/conversion-pdf-document-which-includes-tables-to-csv-file-using-python-or-any-ot/60921462#60921462)

Turns out the deleted post is locked since it was deleted as Spam.

[image: Screenshot of the error displayed when trying to unfollow this post]

Comment: Feels like it's a bug. Following actions counts as vote or something.

Comment: [How do I unfollow a migrated question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350254/256777) exhibits the same behavior. I linked here from there. Maybe both can be fixed with a single tweak.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was fixed at the end of last week. You should be able to follow or unfollow locked posts both from the post itself and from your user profile.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Do you know why I can't follow [this closed / locked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo)? No links except `share`.

Comment: @pkamb It's locked with the "historical significance" lock which prevents most interactions.