# Can't unfollow deleted post

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-posts, follow-post

I can't unfollow a deleted post. This may be a regression, or a corner case which has not yet been reported.

I have very low rep on Economics (currently 105) and my "Following" tab simply says I have no questions which I follow:

[image: You are not following any posts]

And yet I have received multiple inbox notifications for a question I followed which was then deleted, and which has apparently then still been edited by its author:

[image: My recent inbox notifications, 3/4 about GOLD VALUE]

I [posted a question on the Economics meta](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2034/i-get-notified-for-edits-on-a-deleted-post) and Glorfindel helpfully pointed me to [Cannot unfollow locked post from Following tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349629/295232) but ... it doesn't work; as reported above, I don't see the post in the Followed tab.

The "solution" at [How do I unfollow a deleted question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346423/how-do-i-unfollow-a-deleted-question) does *not* work; it only fixes it for users who have the privilege to see deleted questions in the first place.

Comment: Originally posted https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2034/i-get-notified-for-edits-on-a-deleted-post and then reported at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354286/169312 where Yaakov suggested I post a separate bug report.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A user’s [Activity > Following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=following) tab will now display posts that the user followed which were subsequently deleted (deleted status shown through row background color and a text label).

Note: deleted followed posts will only show up on the `Following` subtab on the `Activity` page. They will not show up on the `Followed posts` subsection of the main `Activity` page.

These will be shown even if the user does not have enough rep to see deleted posts (in which case if they click on the link to the post, the post itself will not load).

The user will then be able to unfollow the post from that screen. The row will stay on the page even after it is unfollowed, and the user could refollow it before reloading (to handle misclicks), but will be gone on the next page load.

---

> one follows a post
> said post is then deleted
> unfollowable

Comment: Screenshot for clarification: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJN7x.png

Comment: Thanks for the haiku; will there be a T-shirt?

Comment: I had a hard time finding the location even after I read this answer. The "Followed Posts" widget in your profile does not contain any deleted posts, you have to separately select the "Following" tab. https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/10909/tripleee?tab=following

Comment: @tripleee I just added a clarification to the answer

Answer (score 5):

I'm posting an answer because this *hasn't* been fixed, or it doesn't seem like it, so I don't know why it's [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).  I'm also not sure where else it should go, as I posted [Still can't unfollow deleted posts from Followed tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354526/still-cant-unfollow-deleted-posts-from-followed-posts-tab), which was closed as a duplicate.

Earlier, I followed [this now deleted post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355024/for-any-set-a-of-first-category-there-is-a-borel-probability-measure-such-that), and the button to "Unfollow" from my [Followed Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/798831/ollie?tab=following) tab is not showing anymore.  From [Adam Lear's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352886/349251) to a similar bug report:

> Going forward, you should be able to unfollow deleted posts from both the question page itself and from the "Following" tab on your user profile.

If we accept this as true...then why isn't the button showing?

---

From @RobertLongson's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354289/cant-unfollow-deleted-post#comment1186116_355025):

> I can follow and unfollow deleted posts so perhaps there's some 10K check where there shouldn't be.

Robert has over 19K reputation, so he has certain privileges that having 10K gives you.  Neither I nor @triplee have 10K, so...  It looks like this is a bug specific to non-moderators and sub-10K users.

Comment: I can follow and unfollow deleted posts so perhaps there's some 10K check where there shouldn't be.

Comment: @RobertLongson You have over nineteen thousand reputation, so you are allowed to view deleted posts.   I would be surprised if you *couldn't*.  But yes, I think you are correct.  Neither I nor triplee have 10K, so...

Comment: @Anita's comment links to a post which reveals that the "fix" for 10k+ users happened sort of by accident, but that was all before I posted this question.