# Sub-10K users can't unfollow deleted posts from "Followed posts" tab

Tags: bug, deleted-posts, follow-post

A [bug report about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354289/cant-unfollow-deleted-post) was raised on MSE:  I am still seeing notifications of edits on a post I followed, which was deleted:

[image]

[@AdamLear's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352886/798831) at [How do I unfollow a deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346423/how-do-i-unfollow-a-deleted-question) states that:

> Going forward, you should be able to unfollow deleted posts from both the question page itself and from the "Following" tab on your user profile.

But right now, neither the followed and deleted post nor the "Unfollow" button are showing up in my Followed posts tab.  Those with the [Access to moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege will not be bothered by this problem, owing to the fact that they can see deleted posts, but those of us who don't have that privilege can't.

As the ability to unfollow deleted posts from the Following tab existed before, assuming the quote above is accurate, could we reinstate that ability?

---

**UPDATE**

The [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354289/cant-unfollow-deleted-post) this question was duplicated to is now marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but I am still unable to unfollow a deleted post from my "Followed Posts" tab, so I'd like this to be reopened.  See [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355025/798831) at the duplicate for more details.

Comment: Retagged as a bug, since this is inconsistent with functionality announced by the team.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog then it will be considered as a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354289/cant-unfollow-deleted-post).  Could it not be tagged with both?

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid this still would be a duplicate. Making a feature request to ask that an already-reported bug be fixed doesn't add much more than simply reporting the bug itself. If you have a *specific way* by which a bug should be fixed, post it as an answer there. This doesn't provide anything more than what's in the bug report.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog It's a duplicate, yeah, but the dupe is marked [tag:status-completed], and it's not fixed.  Would it be okay to re-open this, as we really still can't unfollow?

Comment: Ollie, in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352886/282094) it links to [this deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354286/282094) (which ***you*** can't see) which [says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network/354286#comment1184023_354286): "We are no longer following up on bugs posted here. Please make a new post. – Yaakov Ellis♦ Sep 17 at 5:49". --- So reopening is OK.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. Reopened

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This has been fixed (Yaakoved).  See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366525/798831) answer for details.  A confirmation screenshot that this works for all users:

[image]