# "Followed post" list ceased to show the status of the questions and displays deleted questions now

Tags: feature-request, follow-post

I follow all questions that I voted to close. Obviously, this "Followed posts" list on my Activity page is rather longer than shorter, requiring manual clean-up from time to time. In the past, deleted questions did not appear in this list, and if I remember correctly, one could see in this list whether a question had been closed or marked as a duplicate.
This is not the case now. Looking for a reason for this changed behavior, I found this [Meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page) but this problem was not mentioned afaik.
So, I request as a feature to implement the following (prior?) behaviors:

1. Deleted questions should not appear in the "Followed posts" list so I don't have to manually unfollow a deleted (aka non-existing) question.
2. Closed questions or those marked as duplicates should be shown as such in this list so I can unfollow them directly from this list without going to the question page only to find out this question has already been closed/deleted/marked as a duplicate.

As an aside: I find it also weird that when I unfollow a question from this list, it is still retained in the list until I reload the page. I think, previously an unfollowed list was immediately removed from this list.

**Update**: My main problem that deleted questions still appeared in my "Followed posts" list has been resolved. So long, and thanks for all the fish.

**Alas, update again**: NOOO! After a day or two, the deleted questions reappeared in my "Followed post" lists. I hope this is just transitory.

**Update three**
I am being told that the bug of the deleted questions being visible in my "Followed list" is a new design choice. Well, I don't have the insight of other people here but if it is a design choice, then it is not working. As of today, the deleted questions have disappeared again. Someone is flicking switches in the basement.

Comment: Did your reputation get to 10,000? At that point, you can see deleted questions and answers.

Comment: Unless they count this threshold +/- 10%: no.

Comment: Unless you are a moderator, I do not see how you can see deleted questions when you have less than 10,000 reputation. Understand that questions simply closed or marked as duplicate are not deleted questions.

Comment: It was (not the only) unintended behavior after the major December update.

Comment: Based on [Adam Lear’s answer to “How do I unfollow a deleted question?”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352886/986753), I’d guess that it is intentional that deleted followed posts are visible on the “Following” subtab of your “Activity” tab.

Comment: Based on [Yaakov Ellis’s answer to “Can't unfollow deleted post”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366525/986753), I’d also guess that it is intentional that a deleted post is not immediately removed from your “Following” tab when it is unfollowed from there.

Comment: While not specifically about the “Following” tab, there is a general request to bring back the info that questions are closed, which is marked [status-review]: [Lost indication of closed / duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372701/986753).

Comment: There is also a general bug report regarding the lack of a red background on deleted posts: [Posts background on different listings do not change when the post is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372950/986753). There is also a specific bug report regarding this issue for the “Following” tab, in particular for the dark mode on Stack Overflow: [Deleted posts are no longer highlighted in the “Following” tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375828/986753).

Comment: Since your report here seems to be duplicated in the thread [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page) (cf. my previous comments), I’m flagging to close this post as a duplicate.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Totally different problems.

Comment: @Rob No. I can unfollow them from the "Followed post" list. This is not the problem. The problem is, as explained in the question, that I shouldn't have to do this manually - I didn't have to do this in the past, and it doesn't make sense that I have to remove a non-existent question from my list that is shown as an existent question.

Comment: In response to your first [comment to me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374697/followed-post-list-ceased-to-show-the-status-of-the-questions-and-displays-del#comment1254143_374697), you can see [that it's the intended behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352886/282094). As for [your second comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374697/followed-post-list-ceased-to-show-the-status-of-the-questions-and-displays-del#comment1254151_374697), if that's your secret to success (how you accomplish your goals, by addressing people that way), let's see how that works out.

Comment: I am not sure that people telling me that a bug is intended behavior is a valid answer. SO just post hoc justified what happened. But if you all accept this, well, so be it.

Comment: @Mr.T yes, if being told that a bug is "by design" it's valid response. Let's take a simple example. You might think that being able to click the upvote/downvote arrows on your own posts, just to be seeing "You can't vote for your own post" message, is a bug. However, that's exactly how the developers of the site meant it to be, so it's not a bug. It is the site design/UX. To change it, we should post a new [tag:feature-request] question.