# Distinguish between deleted and non-deleted posts in bookmarks and followed posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, bookmarks, deleted-posts

Here is a screenshot of what I see of the first few bookmarks I have on Stack Overflow:

Bookmarks tab:
[image]

Summary Page:
[image]

Since I have more than 10k reputation on Stack Overflow, I have the ability to see deleted posts including those in bookmarks lists. It turns out that the first question "Why do I get "IndentationError: expected an indented block" in my code" has been deleted, however, there is no way whatsoever to distinguish it from the other bookmarks in either the Bookmarks tab or on the summary page.

Apparently, the same thing happens with [followed posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=following) as mentioned in [the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1263358).

Deleted posts used to be indicated with a light red background in the bookmarks and followed posts. Would it be possible to restore this/add a way to clearly indicate when a bookmarked/followed post has been deleted?

Comment: You're not misremembering. The bookmarked deleted posts were previously indicated by a light red background (actually, so light red that I sometimes found it hard to see this on my monitor), but they have not been since after certain GUI changes were made late last year.  Note the issue has been previously reported in this Dec. 9, 2021 [answer](/a/372782/562482).  However, since it's now about 5 months later and the problem has still not been fixed (nor has any sort of official response in comments or as an added tag), I believe it's useful to mention it here again now as a separate question.

Comment: Note that looking at the comments and the [revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/372782/revisions) of that answer, the OP indicated the problem was actually fixed shortly after the original posting, but it was then broken again on Jan. 7, 2022 and, I believe (including from own personal observations), has remained broken until now.

Comment: The same problem happens for [Followed Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=following)

Comment: @Glorfindel: Has the same been implemented in the Summary page as well?

Comment: @Justin good catch - it's only partially completed then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I went ahead and added the "Is Deleted" state to posts being displayed in the profile summary page for Bookmarks and Followed posts alike, as reported in the comments.

We have some cool stuff coming up regarding bookmarks very soon (spoiler alert), and more improvements to UX in the near future.

I'll mark this one as complete, thank you for reporting!

Answer (score 7):

There is now a pink background as well as an indicator that a post has been deleted

- in the [Bookmarks tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=bookmarks) (Thanks, John Omielan):

  [image]
- in the [Following tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=following):

  [image]
- on the [Summary page](/users/current?tab=summary)

  [image]

Comment: Note the Bookmarks tab now also shows deleted posts in the same manner.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: Thanks, could you provide a screenshot? I will include that in my answer.

Comment: This [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFAlB.png) shows one deleted post in my Bookmarks tab.

Comment: This appears to have been completed for the dedicated pages `?tab=bookmarks` and `?tab=following`. It does not appear to have been completed (or it was missed) for the summary page. See ([Summary page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sduVn.png) vs [Bookmarks page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxQn8.png))

Comment: @henry: Deleted *followed* posts are [only shown in the Following tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354289/cant-unfollow-deleted-post/366525#366525). For deleted *bookmarked* posts, you should add an update to your question or post an answer/new question mentioning that it should be done for the summary page as well.

Comment: I'm going to update this question since it's still status-review and not marked status-completed. Thank you for the advice.