# Pluralization issue: "1 bookmarks" in the Following and Bookmarks tabs

Tags: bug, bookmarks, plurals, activity

There's a pluralization issue in the

- Following tab:

  > [image: Pluralization issue in the Following tab: "1 bookmarks"]
- And the Bookmarks tab:

  > [image: Pluralization issue in the Bookmarks tab: "1 bookmarks"]

Comment: [mumbles about something deprecated with something deprecated]. Sigh. If SE can't do proper pluralization, can they not simply do `answers: 1 votes: 6 views: 71 bookmarks: 1`, why keep choosing the worst of both worlds?

Comment: @oleg: That does look a bit confusing.. To me, it looks like `1 votes, 6 views, 71 bookmarks`. But if there's enough spacing between the stats, then it just might work.

Comment: Yeah, or an unobtrusive separator between items (something like a muted vertical line). Ideally, of course, I would prefer them spending 1 tick of the brainpower on adding a single ternary every time there is a "<amount> <thing>" pair in stats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to have been some recent design changes to the Activity page<sup>1</sup>, wherein the "1 bookmarks" statistic was removed / no longer shown:

- Following tab:

  [image]
- Bookmarks tab:

  [image]

---

<sup>1</sup> For more detailed posts, see:

- [Missing space between bounty amount and remaining duration in user bounties page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379832/513150)
- [Distinguish between deleted and non-deleted posts in bookmarks and followed posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379063/513150)