# The [un-]bookmark and "Unfollow" tooltips for deleted posts are barely visible

Tags: bug, status-planned, design, tooltips, accessibility

In light of some recent design changes [regarding the Following and Bookmarks tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378496/distinguish-between-deleted-and-non-deleted-posts-in-bookmarks-and-followed-post), for questions/answers which have not been deleted, the [un-]bookmark and "Unfollow" tooltips show just fine:

- Un-bookmark and bookmark tooltips:

  [image]

  [image]
- "Unfollow" tooltip:

  [image]

However, if a question/answer has been deleted, the transparency of the "Unfollow" tooltip increases, causing it to be barely visible:

[image]

For the [un-]bookmark tooltips, the positioning of each tooltip is on the left of the icon and there is no transparency issue, but the tooltip is dimmed out with the rest of the question summary:

[image]

Comment: Could anyone provide a screenshot of this happening for deleted *bookmarked* posts? I don't have enough rep to see my deleted bookmarks, so I'm assuming this happens for deleted bookmarked posts too.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry I didn't notice the transparency issue difference with the deleted bookmarked post. Actually, I find it a bit strange there's that difference, in particular that a deleted post's Unfollow tooltip is transparent.