# Badge for the first use of the "follow post" feature

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, badge-request, follow-post

We have badges awarded to those who learned and used some site features, first of all Autobiographer and Informed. Scholar, Editor, Supporter, Citizen Patrol, Critic, Custodian also look worth mentioning as examples.

Propose to make a similar badge and award it for the first use of the ["follow post"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/165773) feature.

I have no strong opinion on the name for such a badge. "Follower" looks like a natural candidate.

Comment: as a side note, the more I learn about this feature the more I like it. The idea and implementation look really smart. Useful, elegant, has no undesirable side effects and potential to serve multiple purposes, especially encouraging people to create account and stick to it. Quite a gem

Comment: ... and so "Leader" (bronze) for ~10 posts followed by others, and silver (no name suggested) for a couple of hundred, gold for ~400 followers (total, for however many posts)?

Comment: @Rob given that follow doesn't require anything but creating account these look risky, may tempt some folks create sock puppets with sole purpose to gain these badges

Comment: @Rob I guess it's academic now that the Follower badge suggestion is rejected, but I don't think a Leader badge would be desirable. I sometimes use "follow post" on great posts, but I mainly use it on bad ones that I've downvoted or close-voted, but which I believe have the potential to be improved. If the author *does* improve the post, then I retract my down or close vote, (and may even upvote).

Comment: @PM2Ring, without statistics I suspect few people are so studious, and we've enough metas to it's not the case. It's your choice, and you said that, that's neither always the [case of Leadership, nor the outcome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_disasters#Ancient_era) panegyrized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback. Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future.