# Expand LQ review comment for "me too" non-answers with advice about "follow post" feature

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, not-an-answer, follow-post

The ["follow post"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/165773) feature is convenient for users having the same problem as asked about in the question.

Currently, the system generates the following comment for those who post non-answers asking about updates on the question (when these are flagged and get to Low Quality review queue):

> - This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment
>    
>   “This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation.”

<sup>(for the sake of completeness, comment wording slightly differs when user has enough reputation to add a bounty)</sup>

I propose to expand above comment with advice about the related follow feature, with text like below:

> If you want to get updates on this question, use ["follow post"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661).

Comment: Good idea, I proposed a [similar change](https://stackapps.com/a/8641/34061) to the AutoReviewComments script.

Comment: (gnat feeling slightly envious) your request is dated April 24 - back then I still (mistakenly) thought that this feature is useless :) @Glorfindel

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This string has been updated with details about the Follow feature. Thanks for the suggestion! The fix will be merged in today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 4/15/21:** We've discussed this internally, and this is a relatively small lift. We will get this into our bug-duty rotation. Marking as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) for now because it may take us a while to get to it. Our bug backlog is large, and we are chipping away at it bit by bit.

---

Thank you for the suggestion. Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future.

Comment: Shouldn't that be [status-deferred]?  Unless you think it's actually a bad idea that *shouldn't* be implemented?

Comment: @GavinS.Yancey there is some related discussion in the [answer by Sonic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361188/) on the post about the ticket smash.

Comment: I can't make sense of this explanation sorry. This request is about review UI, which is not merely in the roadmap but undergoing active rework right now ([official announcement here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/165773)). Please consider [edit]ing to clarify if this decline was discussed with developer(s) currently working on review UI rework - and if it wasn't, maybe better pass it to them to evaluate

Comment: @gnat that's fair feedback. I'll discuss this one with the team.

Comment: @Des did you have a chance to talk to them about this request?

Comment: @gnat not yet. Some folks are out this week so we have time scheduled for next week.

Comment: @Des any chance that folks currently working on review UX will have a look at this request?

Comment: after edit with clarification that this was discussed by folks currently working on review UX this answer makes pretty good sense, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update @AnitaTaylor