# Notification about a comment on an answer to my question

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

I would like to have an option to receive notifications when somebody leaves a comment to an answer to my question.

That is:

1. I ask a question.
2. Somebody provides an answer.
3. Somebody else leaves a comment to that answer. I want to be notified about it.

As far as I know, there is no such feature at the moment.

To clarify, I am talking about standard Stack Exchange inbox notifications.

[image: Highlighted inbox notification button]

**Edit 1:** After the discussion in comments I should add that I don't mean some kind of "Follow" button. I mean that notifications for comments on answers to my question should be the default behavior. You **do** want to receive these notifications. Everybody does.

**Edit 2:** OK, OK. May be it's not really everybody. So it could be a button under the question. See discussion under provided answer.

Comment: How about following each answer?

Comment: You can follow an answer. It is a manual process (i.e., you have to click on "follow" for each answer), but it will then notify you of each action done to that answer.

Comment: Following each answer is a workaround. Since we don't have anything better yet, I'm appreciated for it, but I don't really like it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network)

Comment: If you receive an answer to your question, you'll already get an inbox notification for it. From that point, the onus is on you to click "follow" on that answer to continue tracking any further activity on it (including comments, edits, etc.) An additional feature to accomplish the same effect would be superfluous.

Comment: @Spevacus Yes, thanks. Since there is no better option yet, this is useful. But it is easy to forget and sometimes to overlook. And when you need it on a regular basis, this is just boring and silly. And some questions receives dozens of answers.

Comment: "and sometimes to overlook" - especially when somebody or something distracts us.

Answer (score 2):

As we already have the [Follow Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network) feature, I think this would be redundant.  The current system is good enough when wanting to hear about comments, edits, or other activity, on a certain post.  I don't want that to be the default behavior; I don't want to hear about every interaction on every answer to my question whether I like it or not, I like having options.

Comment: OK, you don't want to be forced. But may be it would be OK to have a one single button for it? "Follow all" or something like this.

Comment: @jsv not if it replaces the other follow buttons on each post.  I still like having the option *not* to follow all.  You also said make this the *default* behavior.

Comment: No, I don't mean it would replace old buttons. You will have old "Follow" buttons under each question and you will have "Follow" or "Follow all" or "Follow question" under the question.