# Allow for more granularity of notifications for followed posts

Tags: feature-request, notifications, follow-post

Let me start by saying that I am a big fan of [the follow feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network).

I use it a lot but I ran into a problem that I'm not always interested in edits + comments + answers + anything else at the same time. For example, I would often follow a post and only want to know about any edits to it. And that may end up like this:

[image: Screenshot of the inbox showing eight notifications for the same question. Six of those are about comments, only two about edits.]

Other times I may only want to know about *answers* to a question. And some times I *am* interested in comments.

Currently, there is no way to choose which notifications you receive from a followed post - any activity pings you. This can be too much in some cases.

It would be immensely helpful if there was a possibility to choose which notifications you get:

- comments
- edits
- answers - applicable when following questions
- changes in status - closure/reopen for questions, acceptance for answers, etc.

Comment: An interactive UI for filtering and grouping these in the Inbox would be welcomed too

Comment: @charlietfl I thought about it but decided to just focus on what notifications we get first.