# Group notifications of followed topics (e.g. like comments on own posts)

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, follow-post

When the feature was announced: [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/392799)

I [replied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346295/392799) a year ago with some concerns, of which, the grouping of notifications. I did not get a response, and having tried the feature again today for testing, the notifications are not grouped still, so I thought maybe it needs its own request.

Issue: the inbox can be easily drowned; one notification should suffice, as checking all the changes since last visit is very easy to do once notified once.

> [image: two notifications for a followed question edit in the inbox]