# What percentage of users across SE "follow" posts?

Tags: support, statistics, follow-post

A recent [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368973/392799) included figures of how many use a certain feature. That made me wonder about the *follow-post* feature, because [to me and to others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363387/392799) the way it's implemented is not user-friendly, even though it's a useful feature. So, I'm curious how often and by how many it's used in its current state.

Of course this would not include unregistered (cookie) users; they're still technically users after all (they're allowed to ask and answer on many<sup>?</sup> sites and may or may not constitute the bulk of all-time users).

Comment: I'm following this post...

Comment: .... Would you believe it's an essential tool as a MSE mod and it has saved me hours of work and helped surface issues lots of times?.... Also as someone who likes the non sticky top bar... I want both plox...

Comment: I'm following all posts that hit HNQ from the sites where I'm a moderator so that I can prevent/clean up non-constructive comments when it happens, then unfollow them after they get off from the HNQ. I also follow borderline problematic posts that may be salvageable. And I was following a critical bug report because [the staff told so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411177/adding-html-tags-or-html-tag-like-to-a-title-breaks-rendering/411183?noredirect=1#comment863596_411183)...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *unusable* and what exactly needs fixing. I am constantly following around 70 posts, with new ones added and some unfollowed, so the average is around 70-90. I follow almost every post I downvote and question I vote to close so I am able to be notified on edits and come back to it and reverse my vote or vote to open if needed. To me that feature is highly useful.

Comment: Source: "[The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/282094)": "Users (with the exception of moderators and authorized staff) will not be able to see this information about other users (nor will it be made public in the API, SEDE, or data dumps).". This will have to be a staff answer, if they wish to disclose the information.

Answer (score 5):

Network wide, about **1.1% of users follow posts**.

Per site, Stack Overflow makes the top 10 at **1.76%** of users following at least one post, with the top spot going to [Substrate and Polkadot Beta](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/) at **3.72%** of users (but top sites by percent are mostly due to smaller user count).

In terms of # of followed posts per user, there's a pretty steep drop-off after following a single post

Data from just Stack Overflow on # of posts followed per user

[image: Num of Follows per User by Frequency]

And here's just the top 5 rows

| Num Follows | Freq |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 29,3297 |
| 2 | 34,428 |
| 3 | 8,922 |
| 4 | 3,612 |
| 5 | 1,875 |

Follows are, of course, private, so can only be queried internally.

Comment: I guess this is only active follows? I've followed a few posts until they were "resolved" and I've had even more that I've accidentally followed and quickly unfollowed.

Comment: Correct, this is excluding follows that have a `DeletionDate` (soft delete of following)

Comment: It would be interesting to know the fraction among the mods. I certainly follow post for mod purposes, and likely others too.