# Is there a way to search among my followed posts?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, search, follow-post

Is there a searching key for followed posts analogous to `inbookmarks:mine` for bookmarks?

If the answer is no, may I enter a feature request?

Comment: Tagging this [tag:status-declined] as per [this comment from staff member Yaakov](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network/345684#comment1173596_345684).

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for the feedback. It's a pity it isn't possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was already [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345684/152859) in the past and [declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network/345684#comment1173596_345684) with the following reasoning:

> For the same reason why we can't [add an option to the questions filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network/350053#350053). Requires some big changes behind the scenes to filter by items related only to the user. Bookmarks are public though, different filtering mechanism