# Approved edit to answer or question should generate an email notification, by default

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, notifications, email

On [Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com), I recently proposed an edit to an answer. Since I don't have enough reputation there yet, that edit needed approval. My edit was approved two days later, and I got no email notification for that. That is something that definitely deserves an email notification, *and* that should be the default. I didn't even get an inbox notification actually.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there have never been email notifications for such things and there aren't supposed to be email notifications for such. Thus, this isn't a [tag:bug], rather it's a [tag:feature-request].

Comment: While some people might want such notifications, other people are going to *definitely not* want them. I expect that having such notifications sent would be quite unpopular as either the only way it works or even as a default. At most, this seems like it might be something which users should be able to enable as an option (but there's quite a bit of resistance to adding preference options).

Comment: @Mayken In reply to your first comment: then it's called a design flaw; but ok, go ahead and call it a feature request. In reply to your second comment: of course some people wouldn't want these notifications, then they would turn them off. Because EVERY kind of email notification one MUST be able to turn off (and BTW the current settings are not nearly as granular as they should be). Regarding it being the default or not, yeah I admit, that's subject to opinion. But not being available, no, that's just wrong.

Comment: As is mentioned in the answer here, there's already an existing way for you to get these notifications, but you have to act to get them on a case by case basis (i.e. you'd need to follow any post where you made a suggested edit and wanted a notification of it being applied/approved). So, in effect, this already exists, but with a default of no notification. Frankly, as it currently exists is the basic functionality of how I'd personally want it, as I don't want these notifications in general, but would like the ability to be notified in the rare case where I might want them.

Comment: While it might be nice to see the ability to turn getting such notifications by default on and off, SE has for a very long time been *very* resistant to adding additional personal preferences. Overall, there are multiple things I'd prefer to see as personal preferences substantially  before this particular feature. If receiving such notifications is something you really want to have as a default, it would be possible for you to create a userscript which auto-follows any post on which you make an edit suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

You already get notified through the '+2' notification in your achievement inbox. *Why* is it important you get an email or inbox notification about it? It's not like you have to take an additional action after your edit is approved, right? (Instead, I'd appreciate a notification when a suggested edit of mine is *rejected*, but I digress.)

If you insist on being notified additionally after your edit is approved, I can suggest the [Follow Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232) feature.

<sub>As a side remark: some users, [including me](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1581086/broken-links-images-fixed) suggest *hundreds* of edits every month. I would definitely get annoyed if I got an email every time a suggested edit of mine was approved. I do know we're the exception ...</sub>

Comment: Again, if you don't want to be notified, I'm not saying you'd have to be. I didn't say explicitly that it should be possible to turn this kind of notifications off because I consider it a given in ANY notifications system that EVERY kind of notification can be turned off (and ALWAYS granularly, i.e. allowing me to turn on and off each and every single kind of notification individually, which is another feature that StackExchange lacks).

Comment: Regarding my statement that these being turned on should be the default, yes I was wrong about that (it's not necessarily untrue, I just can't state that with certainty). That's a matter of personal preference so the only way to establish whether the default should be on or off is to have data about what the majority of users would prefer, and I was probably  wrong in my assessment that most people would want that on by default. But it remains that it should be available as an option.

Comment: To answer your question: "Why is it important?" Here's my use case. I asked a q. and got an a., that I couldn't accept as-was (didn't answer the q and made untrue statements). After some constructive back-n-forth in comments, I was able to propose some edits such that, if approved, I was ready to accept the answer. Obviously I cannot be coming back to check every few hours if my edits were accepted. And I assumed I was going to get an email notification. A week or two went by until it occurred to me to go check, and realised my edits had been accepted 2 days after I proposed them.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your use case. It makes sense, but the Follow Posts feature covers that (I think - I don't have it set up to generate emails).

Comment: I'd like to test that by proposing an edit to this answer (I tried adding just a few blank spaces at the end of a sentence) but the stupid 6-character-minimum prevents me from submitting the edit (and yes, that is wrong in itself; I've had legitimate cases in the past where it prevented me from submitting very significant edits, where less than 6 characters made a difference - and yes it could be spaces too). BTW would that generate a notification also for a _rejected_ edit? (or is the rejected edit case already covered?)

Comment: No, that won't generate a notification for a rejected edit. The 6 character limit has been debated countless times, I guess that won't change. For science, you could change my link to the Follow Post feature to its full URL (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network). Be careful not to click the notification inbox after the edit is live, if you read the 'message' I'm sure it won't generate an email. And check your preferences first: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current and then Edit email settings