# If I vote to close a question, am I notified if the OP updates the question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, notifications

Suppose that I have the privilege to vote to **close** a question on some Stack Exchange site.

Suppose further that I encounter a mediocrely-written question and vote to close it. If the OP updates the question, am I notified?  If not, why not? Shouldn't the ones who vote to close a certain question be made followers of that question so that they can consider retracting the vote if the OP has improved the question to a satisfactory degree?

Answer (score 7):

Not unless you [follow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232) the question, no.

> Shouldn't the ones who vote to close a certain question be made followers of that question so that they can consider retracting the vote if the OP has improved the question to a satisfactory degree?

For mediocre questions, which do have a chance to be improved enough, this would make some sense. But when you follow the post, you're notified of *all* edits, even insignificant ones, and all comments as well. There's no way for the system to determine what is a useful edit (that's where we have users for). Some users vote to close very often (especially on Stack Overflow) would get flooded with notifications.

For poor questions which humanly speaking have no chance to be rescued, following the post (automatically or not) makes no sense at all. I wouldn't like it if I had to click 'Following' to unfollow those kind of posts; it's not my fault people post such questions.

I do sometimes follow questions I close (or answers I delete) to watch for important edits, but the current situation, where that is an optional action for the user, works well enough for me.

Comment: What if there were a "digest notification"?  24 or 48 hours after voting to close a certain question, the voter would receive a notification that, once-clicked upon, would lead to a "digest" containing a list of all notifications pertaining to that question, say, with a list of edits at the top and a list of comments below that.  Reading the edit summaries, the voter may determine whether it is worth checking whether the question has been sufficiently improved.  This "digest" form of following questions would also be useful to users who did **not** vote to close a certain question, IMHO.

Comment: That would be a better idea, but I'd still opt out of that, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

If a close voter wants to follow a question, there's nothing stopping them. On the other hand there's no obligation on them to track the question for the rest of their life either, so following a question that's not your own is not imposed on anyone. Some people have voted to close [tens of thousands of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) in the 15 years that these sites have been around and the cumulative effect of getting notified about edits on all of them would just clog up their inboxes with questions they probably don't even remember any more.

If a question is improved or changed sufficiently that it is no longer closable then it won't attract any more close votes in the close queue and in fact remain open votes will push it out of the queue altogether. The close votes it already has will then age away without any manual retractions being necessary. So we already have a no-friction process for cancelling close votes.

Answer (score 3):

Generally: no. Following a post is an opt-in for a user to do. So if you are interested in following a post after close voting, you can do that. However, this is not imposed by the system.

If you are interested in following all posts you have close voted, then consider using the [Following Overcharged](https://stackapps.com/q/9414) userscript allows automatically following anything that was close voted. It is configurable (requires [the extra configuration plugin](https://stackapps.com/q/9403)) to also follow upvotes, or downvotes, or flags, and few other actions.

It is still an opt-in but at least saves a click per post if a user is interested in following specific categories of actions.

Note: It does require a browser which can have userscript manager installed. Which probably excludes mobile browsers.